# Automate Reports Switching From One To Another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have developed several SSRS reports, which I now would like to host on a big screen in a communal area.  How can I set it  up so that my reports automatically change from one report to another please?

Sorry I am very new to SSRS.

Comment: Check this question here from a few years back...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673272/ssrs-how-do-i-rotate-between-reports-in-a-slideshow-manner

This should do what you want if you add all reports as subreports to a main report and set the subreport visibility based on the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on multiple screens around the building. The way I achieve this is to create a subscription to a file location per report as a DHTML output which contains graphics/charts. The timings I use is about every 10mins in office hours but you can set the interval at on your requirements. Setup the folder containing the output files in IIS and set security on the folder.

I then created a simple VB app to look at the URL which has a config file where I could declare the URL and timings for example:-

URL 1 > 30 seconds > URL 2 > 30 seconds

It works really well, I have dashboards around the office with multiple outputs. If your interested, I can add the package (.exe and .config) file for you to use.

Comment: Thank you Andy.  I shall have a look into this.  What I have done at the moment is to create a HTML document which has iframe embedded and then javascript which rotates through the HTML files.

Comment: Hi Tom, I did try it this way originally but I had issues with the page not refreshing properly even though it had changed. Let me know how you get on and if you do need a hand then just let me know.